# What is use of "define_write_method" in ruby , I tried to understasnd it, but did not get it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

```
def define_write_method(attr_name)
  evaluate_attribute_method attr_name, "def #{attr_name}=(new_value);write_attribute('#{attr_name}', new_value);end", "#{attr_name}="
end
```

This is only available in docs but theoritack description is not available, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it's defining a writer/setter method. What is it exactly that you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one of the methods that are added to an ActiveRecord object. AR reads the schema information from the database and create writer methods for all columns.

This way, you can just point your AR-class to the table (or let conventions do this) and have the ability to "write" data into the Object. When you save it, all those attributes will be persisted to the database.